# Excel window moved event

Tags: excel, vba

I am looking to detect any changes to the size or position of my application window. For detecting changes in size this has been working well in my "ThisWorkbook" module:

```
Private Sub Workbook_WindowResize(ByVal Wn As Window)

'Stuff here

End Sub
```

but it doesn't detect when the window is moved (i.e. if it ins't full screen and it is dragged around) or if the window is "snapped" to the top, left or right (i.e. when you drag a window to the left of your screen and it automatically fills the left hand side of the screen). Is there an equivalent for moving of the screen? something like this would be awesome;

```
Private Sub Workbook_WindowMove(ByVal Wn As Window)
```

Thanks!